# Putting in a drawable inside an image view

Tags: android

I am currently trying to put a draw-able inside a image view.

I've made a simple rounded rectangle as a drawable, and then put an imageview inside my layout, but for some reason it's not working.

The actual drawable is not showing up, and I'm left with a blank outline of the imageview container.

I am not sure what the problem is. My code is show below:

drawable speed_view_vw

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#b3ffff" />
    <corners
        android:radius = "3dp"/>
    <size
        android:width = "200dp"
        android:height = "200dp"/>
</shape>
```

and the imageview:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/SpeedDisplay"
    android:src="@drawable/speed_view_vw"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:contentDescription="@string/speed_image_desc"
    android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Currently, I only have a rounded rectangle, but in the end I want to produce something like this:

[image: The two limes move according to parameters]

So that the two bars move according to user parameters

Comment: Are you on Android Studio and did you just made your drawable?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: [At least with me, ALWAYS] it takes some time for the drawables to come up the layouts with this IDE. In layout view, try changing the phone model android version a few times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add intrinsic bounds,in drawable `speed_view_vw`

```
  <size android:width="xxdp"
      android:height="xxdp"/>
```

or try your drawable like this with `layer-list` and will work

---

**EDIT**

Found your issue its with

`http`

replace this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

with this **http:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: Hmm... doesn't seem to work. Would there be some other missing attribute anywhere?

Comment: item tag needs a drawable, it says.

Comment: <shape xmlns:android="http//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" change this as i said and see

Comment: ITS ALIVE!! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: glad that i can help ! dont forget : XD

Comment: @Charitha Goonewardena happy to help:)